# How to check default kvm mmu on a linux kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, kernel, kvm, mmu

I have found that kvm changed tdp_mmu to enabled by default https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20210726163106.1433600-1-pbonzini@redhat.com/

How can I check if my kernel has this parameter enabled?

Can I reconfigure that on a running centos or ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```
cat /sys/module/kvm/parameters/tdp_mmu
Y : enabled
N : disabled
```

Reconfig:

```
sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel
sudo modprobe -r kvm
sudo modprobe kvm tdp_mmu=[Value] # 1 to enable or 0 to disable
sudo modprobe  kvm
sudo modprobe kvm_intel
```